# Custom IQueryable from EF SQL for Azure Mobile App Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

I need to have a SQL query added on to my `IQueryable` in the Azure Mobile App Service backend table controller. I need the `ItemLibrary` table to have a default query as shown. And either replace the `return Query()` that is part of the default table controller or merge it with it.

This is what I need to do for the `GetAllItemLibraries` but I can't get it to work:

```
public class ItemLibraryController : TableController<ItemLibrary>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        MIIToolsContext context = new MIIToolsContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<ItemLibrary>(context, Request, enableSoftDelete: true);
    }

    // GET tables/ItemLibrary
    public IQueryable<ItemLibrary> GetAllItemLibraries()
    {
        using (MIIToolsContext context = new MIIToolsContext())
        {
            string sqlQueryString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ItemSpecification WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT EquipmentItemID FROM dbo.SiteEquipment WHERE EquipmentSiteID = '8FA79274-C5CC-4610-9D6E-A7062D3CE966')";
            string test = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.ItemSpecification";

            return context.ItemLibrary.SqlQuery(sqlQueryString).AsQueryable();
            // return context.ItemLibrary.SqlQuery(test).AsQueryable();
        }

        // possibly merge the SQL IQueryable with the default query?
        // Query.Union([sqlquery])

        // default query
        // return Query();
    }
}
```

I could do the query in Linq and not SQL, but I have no idea how to reference the `SiteEquipment` table from the context of the `ItemLibrary` table controller. I need that to be the default query but still have it tack on any OData from a client.

For those of you who don't know anything about Azure Mobile App Service and want to comment here is an example of the out of the box default table controller wrapper:

```
public class ExampleController : TableController<Example>
{
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Example>(context, Request, enableSoftDelete: true);
        }

        // GET tables/Example
        public IQueryable<Example> GetAllExample()
        {
            return Query();
        }

        // GET tables/Example/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<Example> GetExample(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/Example/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<Example> PatchExample(string id, Delta<Example> patch)
        {
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/Example
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostExample(Example item)
        {
            Example current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/Example/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteExample(string id)
        {
            return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show all the methods `Query()` you have replaced before, as well as the parts you modified yourself. It is best to have a screenshot of the breakpoint debugging to locate the step where the problem occurred, so as to help you better.

Comment: I didn't modify anything else but what I show in the "GetAllItemLibrary" method. I can't debug it as it's running on a remove server and only sends me messages as "internal error". the default "Query()" is out of the box wrapper for Azure Mobile App Service. I didn't make it. I only added the "using" statement and everything in it

Comment: Okey, Can you add table which name like`logInfofortest`, and you can record the return value of your operation step by step.

Comment: Because you can query the data with linq, there is a problem using sql, we need to look at the specific error message.

Comment: I can't query it with linq because I don't know how to get the SiteEquipment table from the Item Library Table. that is part of my question. the other part is how to take an sql statement and send it out as an IQueryable. I'm showing my code to impart intent, so someone can give me an idea how to achieve that intent. Not to get the code I show working but my intent working.

Comment: what you posted doesn't seem to have much if anything to do with my question.... the Azure Mobile SDK already implements IQueryable and Odata. My problem is I can only do a linq query within the context of the ItemLibrary tablecontroller, I don't know how to access the SiteEquipment context to do a linq query using both entities. I didn't complicate It, you just don't understand my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the offer of help. I've been using linq for a long time and would prefer to use it. Just don't know how (or at least a good way) to use the itemlibrary and sitequipment entities in a linq statement when the context of the itemlibrary table controller only lets me do queries against the itemslibrary and nothing else

Comment: Please provide the URL of the `azure-mobile-services` sdk, I will study it.

Comment: Sample Server Code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/backend/dotnet/Quickstart/ZUMOAPPNAMEService

Comment: GitHub of the SDK: https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server

Comment: The problem is this service is all wrapped up to make it easy to setup and use. but that also makes it hard to customize when something doesn't fit it's box. if EF and everything else was exposed it wouldn't be so confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the most elegant way but it is working as needed:

```
public IQueryable<ItemLibrary> GetAllItemLibrarys(string site)
        {
            using (MIIToolsContext context = new MIIToolsContext())
            {
                //create sql param for site param
                var siteParam = new SqlParameter("@Site", site);

                //use sql to access siteequipment id's by current project site
                var items = context.ItemLibrary.SqlQuery("Select * from dbo.MIIToolsItemLibrary where Id in (SELECT DISTINCT ItemLibraryID FROM dbo.MIIToolsEquipment WHERE ProjectSiteID = @Site)", siteParam).Select(i => i.Id).ToList();

                //use linq on local tablecontroller generated query against sql id results
                return Query().Where(i => items.Any(a => a == i.Id));
            }

            //not using default query
            //return Query();
        }
```

Since I didn't know how (or the best way) to access the SiteEquipment linq query object I just used sql for that part and then was able to insert the result into the provided ItemLibrary Query so I can still run odata queries against it.

I also added a "site" parameter so the mobile client applications are only dealing with items related to that project site. just what I wanted.

Comment: I think I have found the cause of your problem. Although your answer can solve your problem, I think this is not the root cause.

Comment: Your `items` used `select` and `where` was used when returning. I think this is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have test it, I think your query string doesn't work because of `EntityData`. So I changed your `test` string and test it.

*It works!*

[image]

```
public IQueryable<ItemLibrary> GetAllItemLibrarys()
{
        using (ZUMOAPPNAMEContext context = new ZUMOAPPNAMEContext())
        {
            string sqlQueryString = "Select * from dbo.ItemSpecification where Id in (SELECT DISTINCT EquipmentItemID FROM dbo.SiteEquipment WHERE EquipmentSiteID = '8FA79274-C5CC-4610-9D6E-A7062D3CE966')";
            string test = "Select TOP 10 * from dbo.ItemSpecification";
            // Due to EntityData, so sql like below
            test = @"Select TOP 10 *,'111' Id,0x0000000000000FA4 Version,null CreatedAt,null UpdatedAt,CAST(COALESCE(NULL,0) AS BIT) as Deleted from dbo.ItemSpecification";
            var a = context.ItemLibrary.SqlQuery(test).ToList().AsQueryable();
            return a;
        }
}
```